Forbidden: Authenticated IAM principal does not seem authorized to make API request. Verify 'Cloud SQL Admin API' and 'Cloud SQL Client' role
I have an Airflow cluster on Kubernetes, maintained by the SRE team. The cluster uses the service account sa_project_a, created from project_a, to authenticate and access the GCP project. I need to implement a Python script to ingest data from BigQuery in project_a and  project_b then write the data to a MySQL database hosted on Cloud SQL in project_b.
The resource mapping
project_a:

sa_project_a

project_b:

sa_project_b

Cloud SQL Instance


project_c:

Airflow Cluster on K8s

The sa_project_a and sa_project_b have the permission on project_b
BigQuery Data Viewer
BigQuery Job User
Cloud SQL Client
Secret Manager Secret Accessor

In the part of ingesting data from BigQuery, there were no permission issues.
def bigquery_to_df(self, query: str) -> None:
    """Query the data from BigQuery with SQL and convert to Pandas DataFrame

    Args:
        query (str): SQL query string
    """
    client = bigquery.Client()
    query_job = client.query(query)
    rows = query_job.result()
    data = [dict(row) for row in rows]
    self.df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

But, To connect to Cloud SQL, I am using the cloud-sql-python-connector Python library.
def create_connect(
        self,
        connection_name: str,
        db_user: str,
        db_pass: str,
        db_name: str,
        database: str,
        lib: str,
    ) -> None:
        """Create the connect cursor to database in Cloud SQL

        Args:
            connection_name (str): Connection's name of Cloud SQL instance
            db_user (str): User id
            db_pass (str): Password
            db_name (str): Database name on Cloud SQL instance
            database (str, optional): Database software that host on Cloud SQL.
            lib (str, optional): Database library to connect the database.
        """
        ip_type = IPTypes.PRIVATE if os.environ.get("PRIVATE_IP") else IPTypes.PUBLIC
        connector = Connector(ip_type)

        def _get_conn() -> pymysql.connections.Connection:
            """Create the pymysql connection to database on Cloud SQL

            Returns:
                pymysql.connections.Connection: the pymysql connection
            """
            conn = connector.connect(
                instance_connection_string=connection_name,
                driver=lib,
                user=db_user,
                password=db_pass,
                db=db_name,
            )
            return conn

        self.db_name = db_name
        self._pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
            f"{database}+{lib}://",
            creator=_get_conn,
        ).connect()
        logging.info(" --> Start the connection!")

When I attempt to create the connection, I encountered the following error:
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientResponseError: 403, message="Forbidden: Authenticated IAM principal does not seeem authorized to make API request. Verify 'Cloud SQL Admin API' is enabled within your GCP project and 'Cloud SQL Client' role has been granted to IAM principal.", url='https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/{project_id}/instances/{instand_id}/connectSettings'

Afterward, I enabled the Cloud SQL Admin API on all three projects and added the Cloud SQL Client role to sa_project_a. I then re-executed the pipeline, but the same error persisted.
To resolve the issue quickly, I generated a new service account, sa_project_b, within project_b (the same project as the Cloud SQL instance) with the same roles as sa_project_a. I stored the credentials in Secret Manager and retrieved them before creating the connection.
ip_type = IPTypes.PRIVATE if os.environ.get("PRIVATE_IP") else IPTypes.PUBLIC
client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
name = f"projects/{self.project_id}/secrets/{self.secret_id}/versions/latest"
request = client.access_secret_version(request={"name": name})
response = json.loads(request.payload.data.decode("UTF-8"))
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(response)
connector = Connector(ip_type=ip_type, credentials=credentials)

And it was able to create the connection without any issues.
I suspect that sa_project_a might not have permission to use the Cloud SQL Admin API, because I used the exact same script but only changed the service account, which was created in the same project as the Cloud SQL instance. sa_project_b can automatically access the Cloud SQL Admin API because it was created in the same project.

2 points.
Firstly, think from where you are creating the connection. It's from the Airflow worker, so, it's the Project C default service account (or the GKE service account) which is used to initiate the connection. Therefore, you have to activate the API on the Project C and grant the Project C Service Account the Cloud SQL Client on the Project B.
Secondly, using service account key file is never a suitable option. Avoid to use it (security issue and so on...). However, it's great for temporary test and validation. You was able to validate that, if you take a service account (here from Project B) with the Cloud SQL client role and the API activated, it works! Now do it from the project C without any keys!

Thank you for assisting me . It's my fault for missing some information in this post. I have also activated the Cloud SQL Admin API on all three projects, but it still didn't resolve the error.

Do you have the correct role on your AirFlow service account? If you use the GKE service account, be sure that this one has the Cloud SQL Client role on the project B

I apologize for the delayed response. I am currently testing your hypothesis, but since the company's system takes a bit of time, I will inform you once I have the results. Thank you for your patience.
